# Capture repeating pattern after const string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need any number of Versions from this string:

```
magic-string: [\"1.0.2.2 \", \"1.2\", \"1.1\"];
```

What I have:

```
[\s""\\]+([\d\.]+)+[\s""\\]+
```

Matches:

```
1.0.2.2
1.2
1.1
```

Fine so far, but I want to ensure that the "magic-string" is available as well and this will not match:

```
any-random-string: [\"1.0.2.2 \", \"1.2\", \"1.1\"];
```

EDIT: 
Working solution in C#:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=^\s*magic-string:\s*\[(?:\s*""(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*"",)?)+)\d+(?:\.\d+)*";
        var matches = Regex.Matches("        magic-string: [ \"1.0\", \"1.2\", \"1.1\" ];", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kc2J2A

Comment: Which language?

Comment: What do you don't want to match ? Ha, I'm confused. Unable to understand the exact requirement.

Comment: @stud3nt the user wants to match the numbers if and only if the string starts with `magic-string`. It's possible in some regex engines, but can yield different answers depending on the language used (lookbehinds or match reset), and it could be *"impossible"* with regex alone in some languages

Comment: C#. Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In languages that support variable-length lookbehinds (like .NET and JavaScript EMCA2018+):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LxcCWX/4)

```
(?<=^magic-string:\s*\[(?:\s*\\"(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*\\",)?)+)\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

How it works:

- `(?<=^magic-string:\s*\[(?:\s*\\"(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*\\",)?)+)` positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches the following

  - `^magic-string:\s*\[` match the following

    - `^` assert position at the start of the line
    - `magic-string:` match this literally
    - `\s*\[` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `[` literally
  - `(?:\s*\\"(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*\\",)?)+` match the following one or more times

    - `\s*\\",` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `\",` literally
    - `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*\\",)?` optionally match the following
    - `\d+` match any digit one or more times
    - `(?:\.\d+)*` match `.` then one or more digits, any number of times (matches `.1`, `.1.1`, etc. where `1` is any number)
    - `\s*\\"` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `\"` literally
- `\d+` match any digit one or more times
- `(?:\.\d+)*` match `.` then one or more digits, any number of times (matches `.1`, `.1.1`, etc. where `1` is any number)

In simple terms, this matches all locations of `0`, `0.0`, `0.0.0`, etc. that are preceded by `magic-string: [\"0.0\", \"` with the substring `0.0\", \"` appearing zero or more times. (`0.0` being a placeholder for all the formats that `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*` matches).

---

You can use the following regex in languages that support `\G` and `\K` tokens (like PCRE):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LxcCWX/3)

```
(?:^magic-string:\s*\[|\G(?!\A)\s*\\",)\s*\\"\K\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

How it works:

- `(?:^magic-string:\s*\[|\G(?!\A)\s*\\",)` match either of the following options

  - `^magic-string:\s*\[` match the following

    - `^` assert position at the start of the line
    - `magic-string:` match this literally
    - `\s*\[` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `[` literally
  - `\G(?!\A)\s*\\",` match the following

    - `\G(?!\A)` assert position at the end of the previous match
    - `\s*\\",` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `\",` literally
- `\s*\\"\K\d+(?:\.\d+)*`

  - `\s*\\"` match any number of whitespace characters, followed by `\"` literally
  - `\K` reset the starting point of the match, any previously consumed characters are no longer in the final match
  - `\d+` match any digit one or more times
  - `(?:\.\d+)*` match `.` then one or more digits, any number of times (matches `.1`, `.1.1`, etc. where `1` is any number)

In simple terms, this matches all locations that are preceded by `magic-string: [\"` or the position of a previous matched followed by `\", \"`.

Comment: Nicely done! @ctwheels what readings would you suggest to become an expert in regex ?

Comment: @stud3nt I've honestly just found StackOverflow to be the best resource. Watch the [tag:regex] tag and learn how different engines vary in ability and syntax. Watch https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew and his responses - he's like the regex god here. Play around with it, look at existing questions (with answers) here and see if you come up with same or better answers, etc. Eventually it comes easy. Try to improve your regex *steps* on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and constantly improve your techniques.